# Cannot access '<init>': it is package-private in 'MicrophoneInfo'

Tags: android, kotlin

i am developing an app kotlin in android 10.0 (api 29)
i need to check the level in dBFS of the mobile microphone by using this method
getSensitivity() of the MicrophoneInfo class and saving the value in my variable.

the library url:
`https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MicrophoneInfo`

but the class seems to be sealed or something like that...

my error:
`"Cannot access '<init>': it is package-private in 'MicrophoneInfo'"`

```
import android.media.MicrophoneInfo
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle

import br.com.kyloren.soundchecker.databinding.ActivityMainBinding

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding
 
    var myMicrophone = MicrophoneInfo();

    var noiseValue = myMicrophone.getSensitivity()






     override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)



         supportActionBar!!.hide()



     }



 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any sort of class that involves interacting with device features or system settings, etc. is never acquired by directly instantiating it yourself.

Call `mediaRecorder.activeMicrophones` or `audioManager.microphones` and it will return a list of `MicrophoneInfo`s. Be sure to use try/catch to watch out for `IOException`s.

By the way, `AudioManager` is a system service. You would get it by using:

```
context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE) as AudioManager
```

I have never used `MicrophoneInfo`. It might be useful to you to know how to find this kind of information out for yourself in the future. I found it by doing the following in Android Studio:

1. Double-press shift to bring up search, and found the `MicrophoneInfo.java` class.
2. Right-click the name of the class near the type of the file and chose "Find usages".
3. Browse the list of places other Android classes refer to MicrophoneInfo, looking for something with a name like "getMicrophone", "getMicrophones", or similar.